# Unable to utilize Spring's RestTemplateBuilder

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to create the following bean in XConfiguration.java:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate xRestTemplate(@Qualifier("restTemplateBuilder") RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return AdfsRestTemplate.builder()
            .restTemplateBuilder(restTemplateBuilder)
            .adfsClientTokenProvider(getXTokenProvider())
            .build();
}

private AdfsClientTokenProvider getXTokenProvider() throws FileNotFoundException{
    return AdfsClientTokenProvider.builder().id("config-credentials").providerUrl(providerUrl)
            .clientId(clientId).resourceUri(protectedResourceUri)
            .enableX509CertificateAuthentication(
                    AdfsKeystoreUtil.getKeystore(keyStore),
                    AdfsKeystoreUtil.getPassword(keyStorePassword),
                    AdfsKeystoreUtil.getAlias(certAlias))
            .build();
}
```

And I am injecting it here:

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("xRestTemplate")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

But I get  this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method xRestTemplate in xxx.XConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="xRestTemplate")


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder' in your configuration.
```

Can someone kindly tell me what configuration issue is going on? I thought i could use Spring's default RestTemplateBuilder?

I am using springframework: 2.4.3

UPDATE:
I did the following, created a new Bean that returns a RestTemplateBuilder and wired it up in my xRestTemplate method.
CustomRestTemplateBuilder.java

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRestTemplateBuilder {

    @Bean("restTemplateBuilder")
    public RestTemplateBuilder getRestTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }
}
```

Now it is throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xQueryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xRestTemplate' defined in class path resource [XXX/XConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'xRestTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code of your XConfiguration.java?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin added

Comment: Did you annotate XConfiguration with the @Configuration annotation?

Comment: Yes i did that already

Comment: Did you inject the `RestTemplateBuilder` in your class? otherwise, it won't load it into the spring container

Comment: @TavoSanchez I did not, i only have 3 occurrences of RestTemplateBuilder, and they are all in XConfiguration. So i did not inject them elsewhere.

Comment: Which SpringBoot version are you using?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin I updated my post to add my spring version of 2.4.3

Comment: Do you have a class with `@EnableWebMVc` on it? If so remove `@EnableWebMvc` as that will interfere with the Spring Boot auto-configuration of Spring MVC. Also make sure you aren't using the reactive stack as well as that will disable the `RestTemplateBuilder` as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum my team is using reactive stack, is there a work around if we are using reactive stack?

Comment: Just create a config method that returns `new RestTemplateBuilder()`

Comment: You would manually need to create the `RestTEmplateBuilder` as a bean, however as you are using the Reactive Stack you might want to reconsider using the `RestTemplate` as it blocks instead of being reactive. You might want to use the `WebClient` instead.

Comment: @Strelok i did as you suggested, still having error

Comment: @AKJ did you found a fix for this?